# Fedora 17: How do I install Python 2.7 into /usr instead of /usr/local?

Tags: python, linux, installation

I want to install Python 2.7 onto my Fedora machine, but it installs it into the `/usr/local/bin`. How do I make it so that won't happen?

I want to do this because the `setuptool` I installed keeps on placing its files into the `/usr/local/lib` path.

Comment: Are you actually using `setuptools` or *a* setup tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below URL, it would give you a hint at least.

link : [how-to-install-locally-python-on-linux-home-directory](http://isezen.com/2011/09/02/how-to-install-locally-python-on-linux-home-directory/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure before you install something it gives you the option where to save it so all you have to type is where you want to save it.

But also if you go into the start menu and right click on the app then click explore, you can drag and drop the app to where you want it to be saved.